# how to divide a short value by int in C

Tags: c, int, short, divide

I have a short value and I want to divide it by an integer value. How can I achieve this in C?

```
short *i;
int divider = 3;
fread(i, sizeof(short), inputfile);
/*write to buffer with i / divider. */
```

Comment: Just typecast the result

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. `i` is a pointer, and you don't initialize it, so it doesn't point to any defined location. `fread` will try to store a `short` value in some undefined memory location. As for the division, what type do you want the result to be, and what do you want to do with it? By "integer", do you mean `int`? `int` and `short` are both integer types. @Isaiah: A cast (not "typecast") is probably not necessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson That was just a test code I wrote. I want to read 2 bytes from file into a short, divide the short value by an int and then print the result as a short. Sorry I am new to C.

Comment: That clarification belongs in the question. How is the `short` object allocated? Is there some particular reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.

```
short i;
int divider = 3;
fread(&i, sizeof(short), 1, inputfile);

short r = i / divider;
```

Note that instead of declaring `i` as a pointer, you declare it as a `short` type and pass its address to `fread`. Then just do the divide.

You may also want to check the return value of `fread`, which indicates how many values were actually read.